# Usage of indexOf on objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have got a json file in the following format as shown below. The following line of code is throwing an error saying "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined"

```
link.style("stroke", function (d) {

    // userID has visited this link
    if (d.user_ids.indexOf(userID) != -1)
       return "red";
}

"links" :
[

{"source" : 2, "source_id" : "1035", "target" : 12, "target_id" : "1015", "user_ids" : [7409,7957,16367]} 

]
```

I am actually getting user input for user ids and highlighting the users path in a d3 force layout containing nodes and links. How to get over this problem?

Comment: `"links" : [{}]` means `links` is an array containing object. You access arrays using index ...

Comment: The objective is to find out whether the user id entered by the user is valid or not and if yes, what is the trajectory of that user in the d3 force layout

Comment: This is a very [basic task](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Predefined_Core_Objects#Iterating_over_arrays) in JavaScript. If the MDN article doesn't help, please show, what exactly is `d`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Without seeing a fiddle with the behavior it is hard to figure out what the problem is.

The code you listed is fine, there is nothing there that should cause an issue.

My guess is that you have an object in the list that does not contain a user_ids property causing that to be undefined.

Try adding the following code:

```
if(d.hasOwnProperty('user_ids')) {
  if (d.user_ids.indexOf(userID) != -1)
    return "red";
}
```

Hope this helps.